# How is it possible for a user to edit a disabled input-field?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I have a HTML-input-field, which is disabled

```
<input type="text" style="width:75%; float:left;" disabled="disabled" name="stadt" id="stadt" data-validation="isset" data-required="true" class="large form-control">
```

in my tracking-software, I can see that some users still edit the value of that field. How can that be?

Comment: They could be editing the DOM, although unlikely. Are you sure that users are editing it and that it's not being given an unexpected value by your code?

Comment: please note that what you get as a post or get request has in no way to follow any validation or restriction that you implement on the client side... maybe your users are just poking around...

Comment: Is it possible a browser (or plugin thereof) is setting the value via autocomplete?  "stadt"="city" (google translate) which seems a typical value that might be getting set.  I've not checked if default browser behaviour sets disabled fields, just "putting it out there" as a possibility.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  .. Yes, I'm pretty sure. The field is static HTML, so no dynamic generated content. I analyze my site via `mouseflow.js` and I can see, that some users are able to edit the greyed-out field.

Comment: Could possibly be bots. Some are able to tamper with forms to try and find backdoors and vulnerabilities

Comment: @freedomn-m .. you are right.. I disabled the field, because I fill it out via jQuery. When the user inputs his zip-code, the name of the city is filled in the "stadt"-field

Comment: @Rory McCrossan .. I don't think these are bots, because the behaviour (mouse behaviour, clicks, etc.) seems to be very human

Comment: Ultimately there's no such thing as an un-editable or un-submittable field.

Comment: @Dave Newton  .. how do you mean that? can you explain it please?

Comment: @crunchy Browser plugins and users can do whatever they want on the client side. They can alter HTML, alter requests, make their own requests, insert/remove form data, etc. There is no substitute for server-side validation.

Comment: Open up the JS console on this page and hide or delete elements in the DOM. You can add or remove attributes to any element as well, including making fields hidden or visible or enabled or disabled.

Comment: @reformed .. sure you `can` do this.. but why the hell should someone do this on a city-inputfield, where you simply have to input your zip-code to the field beside it ? . on my analysis-tool i can see that people CLICK IN THE DISABLED, GRAYED OUT, FIELD.. and make their input there

Comment: As a developer it is irrelevant wondering why users might do this or that in terms of input. You should be coding with the assumption that there will be malicious users. Perhaps you can consider associating cities with the inputted zip code server side? Then you can eliminate this problem field altogether.

Comment: Everything on the client side of your application can be modified by a malicious user. Stuff like [greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) or simply editing your DOM structure is quite trivial. Heck I can even add more input fields to a form, if the server side service counts on the form structure for its safety than you have a huge design problem.

Comment: Does your "tracking-software"/"analysis-tool" tell you which browsers the users that edit your field are using?   Maybe it's a browser-specific "thing" (eg a mobile browser?).   You could try making it read-only, as per suggestion here: http://caniuse.com/#search=disabled

Comment: @freedomn-m .. yes, it is Chrome on Win10